# How do I run this SQLite query on Android: select X from TABLE where X=something AND Y=something

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my table apTable:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+apTable+"
 ("
+idAP+" TEXT PRIMARY KEY , "
+ssID+" TEXT, " 
+testAPid+" INTEGER NOT NULL ,FOREIGN KEY ("+testAPid+") REFERENCES "+testsTable+" ("+colTestID+") ON DELETE CASCADE);");
```

I want to make a query that will give me the idAP rows where, idAP equals a given value and where the foreign key equals another given value.

I'm doing it like this, but it isn't working:

```
 public String CheckAP(String BSSID, String Teste)
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
     String[] params=new String[]{BSSID, Teste};
     Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+idAP+" FROM "+apTable+" WHERE "+idAP+"="+BSSID+" AND "+testAPid+"="+Teste, null);           
     c.moveToFirst();
     int index= c.getColumnIndex(idAP);
    return c.getString(index);    
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: What is the error you getting?

Comment: Please provide details regarding "it isn't working".

Comment: Not to pick nits, but if you're selecting `idAP` where `idAP=BSSID`, what's the point?

Comment: this is just a query to chek if that idAP already exists within the Test row that equals to Teste values..

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this.

Use a database openhelper.

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

And use this to check if you have created your database.

http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/06/tutorial-how-to-access-android-database.html

Answer (score 0):

try this? think the built-in query works just without having to put in the where clause

```
Cursor c=db.query(apTable, idAP, idAP+"="+BSSID+" AND "+testAPid+"="+Teste, null, null, null, null);
```

but why would you want to select idAP if you already know you are selecting a specific idAP? shouldnt you be doing something like this?

```
Cursor c=db.query(apTable, idAP, testAPid+"="+Teste, null, null, null, null);
```

:S