# query to a SQLite DB in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in DB called TABLE_3 which has several columns....and I wanna do a query to that table using conditions for two of its columns

KEY_SPEED>prefix

and
KEY_USER_ID_=user_id

but I don't know how to write it...can someone help me with that...here is how my query looks with only one of the conditions....How should this look with 2 conditions?

```
public Cursor getViteze(int prefix,int user_id)
{

    Cursor mCursor=db.query(TABLE_3, new String[]{KEY_ROWID_3,KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_LATITUDE,
            KEY_SPEED,KEY_TIME,KEY_USER_ID_},
    KEY_SPEED + ">" + prefix,null,null,null,null);
    return mCursor;
}
```

Thx!

UPDATE:

```
public Cursor getViteze(int prefix)
{

    Cursor mCursor=db.query(TABLE_3, new String[]
```

{KEY_ROWID_3,KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_LATITUDE,
                KEY_SPEED,KEY_TIME,KEY_USER_ID_},

```
    KEY_SPEED + ">" + prefix +" AND "+ KEY_USER_ID_ + "=" +
```

3,null,null,null,KEY_SPEED + " DESC");

```
    return mCursor;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition argument is like WHERE clause in SQL, so you can concatenate your conditions with AND and OR, something like the following,

```
KEY_SPEED + " > " + prefix + " AND KEY_USER_ID_=user_id"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994506/how-do-i-run-this-sqlite-query-on-android-select-x-from-table-where-x-something

Comment: don't quite understand your comments. As long as you concatenate your string as it would for SQL, it should return the result you are looking for. In case querying for text column, just add single quote like " AND KEY_USER_ID='" + user_id + "'"